# Third party sdk integration through admob is throwing Classcast exception

Tags: admob, classcastexception, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying to integrate third party sdk using **admob mediation**.

Ad network has provide adapter for the same. SDK is initialized properly as far as I can see initialization log. But on ad request, its giving the following exception:

```
Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter
Could not request interstitial ad from adapter.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.mediation.nexage.NexageAdapter cannot be cast to com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventInterstitial
    at com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter.requestInterstitialAd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter.requestInterstitialAd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfj.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzey$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:115)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:117)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.e.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:34)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Could not request ad from mediation adapter.
```

I searched a lot regarding this but could not find any help.

Answer (score 0):

found the reason for exception. 
It was occurring because of the incorrect ad setup. Didn't mention correct package name.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, i've the same problem, which package name are you talking about?

Comment: Millennial media can be integrated using two different adapters: nexage and millenialAdapter. By mistake, in mediation network(AdMob), i configured using millenialAdapter (millenial adapter package name) and implemented nexage :/.